# Scalable statistics database

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-schema

I need to build an affiliation system for an on-line retail store. Its database (MySQL) should provide for their affiliates:

- time interval filtering
- affiliate links with views, clicks and their referrals
- customers and orders (just counts)
- products and product categories
- CTR, earnings, etc. - some can be aggregated via PHP script

So I basically have two options:

1. store everything in one table (in key-value pairs) and pull all the data from that table
2. make tables on everything

Can somebody please explain what should I do, and what are the downsides and upsides of either variant? I understand there are some performance considerations involved but I have no data to back it up whatsoever.

Comment: There is missing information and you may want to have an affiliates table, and you may need more tables, or modify existing ones. For example, to get the earning, you may need to modify the existing sales table to have an affiliate id.  For counts of customers and orders that could be in an affiliate table, if calculating it is slow, otherwise the customer/order tables could have an id for affiliates, so you can fetch the data.  Affiliate links may have a new table if an affiliate can have more than one link.

Comment: @JamesBlack yes, I already did all that. but what I'm asking is whether I should reuse those tables to put statistic columns in there, or just store all the stats in a new, key-value pair table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your affiliates data to be historical, so they can see how it changed over time, then a separate table would be better.

If you decide you never want to offer that, and just give them a snapshot in time, then adding it to the table is better.

Personally, I would go with a separate table referenced by the affiliate id, so they can look at a graph of how their information changes over time.

Now, if you store the data, for example, every week a new row, then you lose the ability for them to look at changes by the day, or some other time interval that is smaller than what you stored, and it is harder to filter based on product, in case they changed their marketing approach and want to see the effect.

So, I would go with option 3, which is to pull the data on demand, so the user can filter it however they want, but, you can also have a standard approach that is executed and ran once/wk, if that is a reasonable timeslice.

I would cache those results in a NoSQL database, mainly because it would be faster to retrieve, since you can just get the javascript and send it directly to the user.

If you have to pull data on demand, then also cache that in the NoSQL database, as that is where you look first to see if the request can be satisfied there, before you go to the actual database.

You can also allow the affiliate to set their own selection criteria, and each day just execute those custom criteria so they don't hit the real database just to get their information.

That is the key, limit affiliates need to go to the real database, put their information somewhere else, unless you have to go to that database, to reduce any impact from the affiliates that could impact the customers.

Answer (score 0):

**store everything in one table (in key-value pairs)**

This method is using MySQL as a key-value store. In this case, you don't have a well-defined schema. This is an advantage, because it is very easy to change the data schema. It is also a disadvantage, because you don't notice when data is missing or inconsistent.

**make tables on everything**

This forces you to think about your data structure, but it may be a hassle to fit all your data in your tables.

I would suggest you try to make tables. It is a good thing to think about your data structure at the beginning of your project, and making tables force you to structure data correctly. If this really does not work out for you, you can always use one table or some NoSQL solution.